# SpringBoot2 doesn't see static javascript after deploy to Heroku

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a working (localhost) application on `SpringBoot2` + `jQuery` + `Ajax`. Spring security is configured. The application has a page displaying all users (admin panel).
I deployed the application on heroku. I connected add-on heroku-postgres. Initialized the database (as on localhost) with test values ​​(username: admin, password: admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER). There are 3 tables in the database: user, roles and user-roles (many-to-many). Through DATACLIPS I can see records in these tables in heroku-postgres, I successfully login to my site using admin/admin but for some reason the data (list of all users) is not displayed on the web page.
I can't figure out why!

My settings:

1. pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.khilkevichigor</groupId>
    <artifactId>buyer-shopping</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>buyer-shopping</name>
    <description>International shopping application</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <spring-boot-admin.version>2.3.1</spring-boot-admin.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
        <testcontainers.version>1.15.0</testcontainers.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web-test-client</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssqlserver</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-admin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertiesEncoding>UTF-8</propertiesEncoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

2. application.properties:

```
# for heroku
spring.datasource.url=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/buyer}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:buyer}
spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD :buyer}
server.port=${PORT:5000}
# for init db by admin
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
#spring.datasource.schema=classpath:schema-postgres.sql
#spring.datasource.data=classpath:data-postgres.sql
```

3. main.js with ajax requests to rest controller:

```
const baseRestUrl = detectBackendUrl();
function detectBackendUrl() {
    if (location.href.indexOf('localhost') === 0) {
        return "https://shuba.herokuapp.com/";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
//GET all users
getAllUsers();
//функция получения всех юзеров
function getAllUsers() {
    $.getJSON(baseRestUrl + "/admin/users/rest", function (data) {
        var userRow = '';
        var userId = '';
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            if (key === "id") {
                userRow += '<tr>';
                userRow += '<td>' + value.id + '</td>';
                userId = value.id;
            }
            if (key === "username") {
                userRow += '<td>' + value.username + '</td>';
            }
            if (key === "roles") {
                var rolesObj = value.roles;
                var rolesName = '';
                $.each(rolesObj, function (key2, value2) {
                    if (key2 === "name") {
                        rolesName += value2.name + ';' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                    }
                });
                userRow += '<td>' + rolesName + '</td>';
            }
            userRow += '<td><a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnEditUser' + value.id + '" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-example-modal-md" onclick="editUser(' + value.id + ')" role="button">Edit</a></td>';
            userRow += '<td><a class="btn btn-primary" id="btnDeleteUser" onclick="deleteUser(' + value.id + ')" role="button">Delete</a>' + '</td>';
            userRow += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#users-table').append(userRow);
    });
}
//GET all unchecked roles from server for Add page (показываем роли с сервера на странице добавления юзера)
$('#nav-adduser-tab').click(function () {
    $('#add-all-roles').empty();
    getAllRolesForAdd();
});
//POST user
$('#btnAddUser').click(function () {
    //валидируем форму Add
    if ($('#inputAddUsername').val().length < 3) {
        $('#warningAddUsername').text("Username not valid").show().fadeOut(2000);
    } else if ($('#inputAddPassword').val().length < 3) {
        $('#warningAddPassword').text("Password not valid").show().fadeOut(2000);
    } else if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length < 1) {
        $('#warningAddRoles').text("Roles not valid").show().fadeOut(2000);
    } else {
        var addUser = {};
        addUser.username = $('#inputAddUsername').val();
        addUser.password = $('#inputAddPassword').val();
        addUser.roles = getCheckedRoles();
        $.ajax({
            url: baseRestUrl + '/admin/users/add/rest/',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(addUser),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function () {
                var table = $('#users-table');
                table.empty();
                $('#nav-allusers-tab').tab('show');
                getAllUsers();
                //очищаем форму Add
                $('#inputAddUsername').val('');
                $('#inputAddPassword').val('');
                //очищаем чекбоксы тк функция вызывается двумя объектами и роли в JSON добавляются
                $('#add-all-roles').empty();
                //старый вариант очистки чекбоксов
                // $('#chbAddRoleAdmin').prop('checked', false);
                // $('#chbAddRoleUser').prop('checked', false);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("error Add: " + error);
            }
        });
    }
});
//GET edit
function editUser(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: baseRestUrl + '/admin/users/edit/rest/' + id,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function (editData) {
            $('#modal-title').text('Edit user: ' + editData.username);
            $('#modalEditId').val(editData.id);
            $('#modalEditUsername').val(editData.username);
            //пустая строка для ввода нового пароля
            var emptyPassword = '';
            $('#modalEditNewPassword').val(emptyPassword);
            var editUserString = JSON.stringify(editData);
            $('#edit-all-roles').empty();
            //передаем объект юзера в виде строки чтобы достать чекбоксы с галками
            getAllRolesForModal(editUserString);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
//PUT edit
$('#btnSaveEdit').click(function () {
    //валидируем форму Edit
    if ($('#modalEditUsername').val().length < 3) {
        $('#warningEditUsername').text("Username not valid").show().fadeOut(2000);
    } else if (($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')).length < 1) { //?????? УПРОСТИТЬ
        $('#warningEditRoles').text("Roles not valid").show().fadeOut(2000);
    } else {
        //формируем JSON
        var editUser = {};
        editUser.id = $('#modalEditId').val();
        editUser.username = $('#modalEditUsername').val();
        editUser.password = $('#modalEditNewPassword').val();
        editUser.roles = getCheckedRoles();
        $.ajax({
            url: baseRestUrl + "/admin/users/edit/rest",
            method: 'PUT',
            data: JSON.stringify(editUser),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function () {
                var table = $('#users-table');
                table.empty();
                $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
                $('#nav-allusers-tab').tab('show');
                getAllUsers();
                //очищаем чекбоксы тк функция вызывается двумя объектами (Add and Edit) и роли в JSON добавляются
                $('#edit-all-roles').empty();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        })
    }
});
//DELETE user
function deleteUser(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: baseRestUrl + '/admin/users/delete/rest/' + id,
        method: 'DELETE',
        success: function () {
            //стираем таблицу и заново отображаем всех юзеров
            var table = $('#users-table');
            table.empty();
            getAllUsers();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    })
}
//получаем все роли (unchecked чекбоксы) с сервера для Add
function getAllRolesForAdd() {
    var roleRow = '';
    $.getJSON(baseRestUrl + "/admin/users/roles/rest", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            roleRow += '<div class="form-check-inline">';
            roleRow += '<label class="form-check-label">';
            roleRow += '<input type="checkbox" ';
            roleRow += 'id="' + value.id + '" value="' + value.name + '" class="form-check-input">' + value.name + ''; //убрал chbRole у id
            roleRow += '</label>';
            roleRow += '</div>';
        });
        $('#add-all-roles').append(roleRow);
    });
}
//получаем все роли (unchecked чекбоксы) для модалки и проставляем галки
function getAllRolesForModal(editUserString) {
    var roleRow = '';
    $.getJSON(baseRestUrl + "/admin/users/roles/rest", function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            roleRow += '<div class="form-check-inline">';
            roleRow += '<label class="form-check-label">';
            roleRow += '<input type="checkbox" ';
            //проверяем роли с сервера и проставляем галки
            if (editUserString.includes(value.name)) {
                roleRow += 'checked';
            }
            roleRow += ' id="' + value.id + '" value="' + value.name + '" class="form-check-input">' + value.name + ''; //убрал chbRole у id
            roleRow += '</label>';
            roleRow += '</div>';
        });
        $('#edit-all-roles').append(roleRow);
    });
}
//функция получения ролей (checked checkboxes) с форм Add и Edit
function getCheckedRoles() {
    var roles = [];
    $.each($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'), function () {
        var role = {};
        role.id = $(this).attr('id');
        role.name = $(this).attr('value');
        roles.push(role);
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(roles));
    return roles;
}
```

4. Procfile:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/buyer-shopping-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

5. SecurityConfig:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/home").access("hasRole('USER') or hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .anyRequest().anonymous() //для того чтобы /login не был доступен для авторизованных пользователей
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login") //страница логин недоступна авторизованным пользователям (пришлось закоментировать что б работало)
            .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler()) //стратегия перенаправления после /login
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/perform_logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
            //перенаправляем не на /403 а на домашнюю
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/home") //обработка ошибок (400)
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();
}
```

6. Init dataBase:

```
/**
 * Init dataBase username: admin, password: admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN
 */
@PostConstruct
public void initDb() {
    Role role = roleRepository.getRoleByName("ROLE_ADMIN");
    if (role == null) {
        role = new Role();
        role.setName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        roleRepository.save(role);
    }
    assert roleRepository.getRoleByName("ROLE_ADMIN") != null;

    role = roleRepository.getRoleByName("ROLE_USER");
    if (role == null) {
        role = new Role();
        role.setName("ROLE_USER");
        roleRepository.save(role);
    }
    assert roleRepository.getRoleByName("ROLE_USER") != null;

    User user = userRepository.findUserByUsername("admin");
    if (user == null) {
        user = new User();
        user.setUsername("admin");
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("admin"));
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
        Role roleAdmin = roleRepository.getRoleByName("ROLE_ADMIN");
        Role roleUser = roleRepository.getRoleByName("ROLE_USER");
        roles.add(roleAdmin);
        roles.add(roleUser);
        user.setRoles(roles);
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
    User admin = userRepository.findUserByUsername("admin");
    assert admin != null;
    Set<Role> roles = admin.getRoles();
    assert roles.size() == 2;
}
```

P.S. I have a local Postgres database connected via docker. On localhost I do the same, and when I run the application locally - everything works - I can see on the web page all users (admin/admin) from the database.
There is a suspicion that the problem is in the url of ajax requests. Maybe on heroku it's not localhost but something else.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

On Heroku I only use one buildpack "heroku/java". At the root is package.json with the following content ([link](https://medium.com/simplejs/deploy-static-files-on-heroku-7e55e01a5df9)):

```
{
  "name": "shuba",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Buyer international application",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "serve": "^10.0.1"
  },
  "author": "Igor Khilkevich"
}
```

As I understand it, SpringBoot2, after deploying to Heroku, stopped seeing static javascript main.js which lies in `src / main / resources / static / js / main.js`

How to fix it?

Comment: I assume my pom is not configured correctly, namely the <build> section